# Page Object Mode with node, ES7, puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, puppeteer

I recently started utilizing Puppeteer for e2e testing (I have some experience with Selenium Web Driver) and I could not find anything in the documentation discussing POM pattern. Are there any examples available how to implement this correctly in node/ES7 within Puppeteer?

Let us say I have a simple script that tests the login functionality of a page:

```
(async () => {
...

     await page.goto(url, {
        timeout: 5000
    });

    await page.waitFor('input[id=userId]');

    await page.type('input[id=userId]', 'John Doe');
    await page.type('input[id=password]', 'password1');
    await page.click('button[type="submit"]');
    await page.waitFor('p.success-msg');
...
}();
```

Typically, we would have a Page Object Model for the login page. How would I create a basic POM for the above page and integrate it with my script? How would you call the POM in my test script in this environment?  Would I use `import`?  I am just looking for a basic 'hello world' example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At the most basic level, POM states that every page has its own class containing utility methods to interact with that page.

To achieve this with Puppeteer, we use ES6 classes to create the classes that contain utility methods for their respective pages.

**Folder Structure**

```
test/
  main.js
  pages/
    - HomePage.js
    - CartPage.js
    - ProductDetailPage.js
```

**HomePage.js**

```
export default class HomePage {

    constructor(page) {
        this.page = page;
    }

    async getTitle() {
        return this.page.title();
    }
}
```

**main.js**

```
import HomePage from "pages/HomePage";

const HP_URL = "https://google.com";

(async () => {

    await page.goto(HP_URL);

    const hp = new HomePage(page);

    const title = await hp.getTitle();

    console.log(title);

})();
```

Comment: Right that makes sense, but how would one create a `class LoginPage {}` and then integrate that with the actual test script?  Would I use ES6 `import` ?  If you could make your example more relevant to my specific use case that would be very helpful.

Comment: See my edit for a more complete example -- you would export `LoginPage` and import it in your main test script

Comment: Ah I see, this makes more sense.  So in POM every page would be it's own class, correct?  But in say, a single page application, such as my Angular app, would every component have its own POM, say the login.component.ts?  Also, let us say we have a complex app with 30 components, would I have 30 POMs and only one test script?

Comment: Also, I see you placed  `const title = await hp.getTitle();` I though according to POM all of the functionality related to page flow should be in the the page object?

Comment: For the single page app, if the app is easily split into routes and URLs, you can stick to doing it by page, otherwise you would create classes for each *feature* (i.e. `loginFeature.js`, `emailFeature.js`, etc.). Regarding `await hp.getTitle()`, the variable `hp` is the page object for the homepage, so any methods specific to the homepage should be accessible through `hp`

Comment: Ok I see, I just wish I did not get that `import` syntax error since I am using typescript...